# Querying 3 mysql tables to create an HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### Goal

I'm trying to draw up a restaurant menu in HTML using MySQL queries.

### MySQL Tables

**Categories**

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id | nom_categorie   | dimensions |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | pâtes           | 1-2        |
| 2  | ailes de poulet | 3-4-5      |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Dimensions**

```
+---------------------+
| id | dimension      |
+---------------------+
| 1  | Petit          |
| 2  | Gros           |
| 3  | Unité          |
| 4  | Repas (6)      |
| 5  | Repas (12)     |
+---------------------+
```

**Repas**

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id | repas      | prix            |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | spaghetti  | 8.75,11.75      |
| 2  | lasagne    | 9.95,13.25      |
| 3  | régulières | 0.95,9.50,11.95 |
| 4  | piquantes  | 0.95,9.50,11.95 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

### Desired outcome

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Pâtes                                |
+--------------------------------------+
|           |   petit    |    gros     |
+--------------------------------------+
| spaghetti |   8.75     |   11.75     |
| lasagne   |   9.95     |   13.25     |
+--------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------+
| Ailes de poulet                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|             |  Unité | Repas (6) | Repas (12) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Régulières  |  0.95  | 9.50      | 11.95      |
| Piquantes   |  0.95  | 9.50      | 11.95      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

### Current outcome

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Pâtes                                |
+--------------------------------------+
|           |    1       |    2        |
+--------------------------------------+
| spaghetti |   8.75     |   11.75     |
| lasagne   |   9.95     |   13.25     |
+--------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------+
| Ailes de poulet                      |
+--------------------------------------+
|             |    3   |   4   |   5   |
+--------------------------------------+
| Régulières  |  0.95  | 9.50  | 11.95 |
| Piquantes   |  0.95  | 9.50  | 11.95 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

### Current code

```
function catalogue_complet($mysqli) {
    $categories = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY nom_categorie ASC");
    $produits = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM produits ORDER BY id, prix ASC");
    $dimensions = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM dimensions");

    while($categorie = mysqli_fetch_array($categories))
    {
        echo "<h2>".$categorie[1]."</h2>";

        echo "<table class='catalogue'>";
            if(!empty($categorie[2]))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
                    $array_categorie = explode("-",$categorie[2]); 
                    foreach($array_categorie as $categorie)
                    {
                        echo "<th>".$categorie."</th>";
                    }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            while($produit = mysqli_fetch_array($produits))
            {
                if($categorie[0] == $produit[2])
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$produit[1]."</td>";
                        $array_prix = explode(",",$produit[2]);
                        foreach($array_prix as $prix)
                        {
                            echo "<td class='prix'>".$prix."</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        echo "</table>";            
    }
}
```

### Other details

I may have a few errors slipped in with keys (example: $produit[2]) as I've simplified the tables, but I do have the proper information in my output. As I've mentioned above, my problem lies in the fact that I get the dimension ID as entered in my table `repas`. I can't figure out how to get the proper information (`Ailes de poulet` and `Pâtes`) to show up ?

Comment: it is getting harder and harder nowadays to figure out what OP are asking....

Comment: How is this unclear? I need to query a table and I'm not getting the proper information, and I can't figure out how to get it. I thought it would be clear that I'm trying to do just that, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: You're going to want to further normalize your data - keeping it stored in a comma-separated list is **guaranteed** to be trouble.  You're also missing any in-db links connecting `categories` and `repas` - the only way to tell currently is because of the comma-separated list, which isn't going to help long-term.  Fixing your data will go a long way to helping you out in the future...

Comment: Why all the chickens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a working solution. Please excuse the length of the code, and as mentioned in the original post, some differences may occur when looking at the tables in the question, but it is simplified to focus on the desired effect.

Bottom line, the code below produces the table with title (ex: `Pâtes`), and each product and price line (ex: `Lasagne | 9,95 | 13,25`)

```
function catalogue_complet($mysqli) {
    $categories  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM catalogue_categories ORDER BY nom_categorie ASC");
    $produits    = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM produits ORDER BY id, prix ASC");
    $dimensions  = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM dimensions");

    while($categorie = mysqli_fetch_array($categories))
    {
        echo "<h2>".$categorie[1]."</h2>";

        echo "<table class='catalogue'>";
        mysqli_data_seek($produits, 0);

        if(empty($produits))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".AUCUN_PRODUIT."</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            while($produit = mysqli_fetch_array($produits))
            {
                // Dimensions -----------------------------------------------------------
                if(!empty($categorie[3]))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    while($dimension = mysqli_fetch_array($dimensions))
                    {
                        $array_dimensions = explode("-",$categorie[3]);
                        foreach($array_dimensions as $dim)
                        {
                            if($dim == $dimension[0])
                            {
                                if($i == 0)
                                {
                                    echo "<th>&nbsp;</th>";
                                }
                                echo "<th>".$dimension[1]."</th>";
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                // Produits -------------------------------------------------------------
                if($categorie[0] == $produit[4])
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$produit[1]."</td>";

                    $array_prix = explode(",",$produit[3]);
                    foreach($array_prix as $prix)
                    {
                        if( empty($prix) or ($prix == "0"))
                        {
                            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<td class='prix'>".str_replace(".",",",$prix)." $</td>";
                        }
                    }

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically need to get the column names of your tables correctly.
In your current code, you are not using the dimensions table at all, although you have queried it.
Keep the names of all dimensions in an array, and refer them whenever the id is known.

Storing the dimensions in an array.

```
$dimensions = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM dimensions");
$dim_arr = Array();
if($dimensions){
    while($d = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($dimensions)){
        $dim_arr[$d['id']] = $d['dimension'];
    }
}else{
    die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Using them inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach($array_categorie as $categorie)
{
    //Perform error checking here - if(isset($dim_arr[$categorie]))
    $dim_name = $dim_arr[$categorie];
    echo "<th>".$dim_name."</th>";
}
```

This should display the headings.